# Is there any referral incentive for Careers 2.0?

Tags: discussion, jobs, referrals, employers

I'm about to send an email to my manager and HR director suggesting that they try searching for programmers on Careers 2.0.

Just as I was about to hit send, I thought: "maybe there is some referral program where I get some kind of reward (real or virtual) if my company starts using Careers?"

So, is there anything like this, or should I just hit send?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should just hit send.

If your team is looking to hire and you find someone on Careers, the reward is a better team.  And that's real.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget about the other incentive which is that we will love you forever.

<3

Comment: But the real question, are we still eligible to be poked with a pointy stick?